Is there a low-maintenance way to implement microservice chassis pattern in Python?
Context: I'm developing my first microservice project, and still trying to wrap my head around some best practices.
The project structure is not that complicated:
DaProject/
 +- ServiceA/
 |  +- main.py
 |  \- Dockerfile
 +- ServiceB/
 |  +- some_ServiceB_specific_lib/
 |  +- main.py
 |  \- Dockerfile
 \- docker-compose.yml

Now, as I played around with implementing a couple of services, I've figured out some of the cross-cutting concerns for my project. Since all services will be implemented in Python, I want to take care of those concerns using Service Chassis pattern.
The question is, is there a simple, but decent way to do that?
For example, if I do this:
DaProject/
 +- Chassis/
 |  \- __init__.py
 +- ServiceA/
 |  +- main.py
 |  \- Dockerfile
 +- ServiceB/
 |  +- some_ServiceB_specific_lib/
 |  +- main.py
 |  \- Dockerfile
 \- docker-compose.yml

then I will need to reference the Chassis package from within the services.
What I have thought about:

I can't just reference ../Chassis in any Dockerfile, as it is outside of the build scope. Okay, that makes sense.
I don't want to manually copy the chassis into each service directory whenever I happen to update it. It's a very simple solution, but high-maintenance and error-prone.
Hardlinking the directory is a hack, and will likely break if the code is moved somewhere else.
Implementing a local pypi repo sounds like a high-maintenance way to handle it. Perhaps it would be more worth it I was implementing a more abstract and reusable library, not something as project-bound as this.
Googling pointed me towards 'git submodule' concept... but I have only basic familiarity with Git, and so I can't really judge how complex this solution is.

Is there any other way I'm not aware of? Or should I bite the bullet and learn the submodule feature?
